# Cleanly convert offset from midnight to time object in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a number that represents milliseconds after midnight.

I wish to take a number such as `3600000` and get a Time object (`1:00am` in this example).

Is there a clean way to do this in MomentJS without writing my own custom code for it?

Comment: 360000 milliseconds is 360 seconds which is only 6 minutes. How did you get 1:00 AM?

Comment: I don't know moment but if you want to use vanilla JavaScript you could do: `var d = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0); d.setMilliseconds(360000);`

Comment: And if you just want hours:minutes after midnight you could just do some division. `function ms2t(milliseconds){ var minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000 / 60); return Math.floor(minutes / 60) + ":" + ("00" + (minutes % 60)).slice(-2); }`

Answer (score 1):

Moment doesn't have a `Time` object, but you can certainly produce a string.

```
moment.utc(3600000).format('h:mm a')  // "1:00 am"
```

Note that the use of `moment.utc` is preferred over just `moment` in this particular case, to avoid possible issues related to daylight saving time.